# Having an image as a background image, stretching itself until end of page

Tags: html, css, image, stretch, document-body

I'm trying to have a HTML image fit a page(the whole body) so that it will auto-stretch if more content is added (overflow). I don't want to have an absolute positioned image. I've been trying this for 3 days, but I can't get it working.

Please use only CSS and HTML.

Thank you!

Comment: You will need to set the heights of both the `<html>` and `<body>` tags to 100%, and then set the height of the image to 100%. Even so, you will still need to set the image's positioning as absolute, otherwise you won't be able to place anything *on top* of it.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried and why it did not work. [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/. Demo here: http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/0431-01_responsive_background_image_demo/responsive-full-background-image-demo.html.

Answer (score 0):

set height of `html` to `100%`

```
body {
   background-image:url("path/myImage.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body
  {
    background-image: url('path/to/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  }

 html
  {
     height: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
   background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_FOSmVKg.jpeg");
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

only this much code is enough